# How can i give rtp: protocol as a src in embed player in html?

Tags: html, streaming, video-streaming, flash, rtp

i am trying to stream live video from  url  rtp://224.168.116.253:4568 using flash player can somebody tell me how is that possible pass this url parameter as src, how can i make it work, i have checked it with the player player is streaming video smoothly now i want to do embed on code and show it on web.

Here is my webpage that i am working on :

```
<html>
    <title>Live Streaming</title>
    <body>
        <OBJECT id='mediaPlayer1' width="480" height="550" 
                classid='CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95' 
                codebase='http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701'
                standby='Loading Microsoft Windows Media Player components...' type='application/x-    oleobject'>
            <param name='url' value="rtp://224.168.116.253:4568">
            <param name='fileName' value=url>
            <param name='animationatStart' value='true'>
            <param name='transparentatStart' value='true'>
            <param name='autoStart' value="true">
            <param name='showControls' value="true">
            <param name ="ShowAudioControls"value="true">
            <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true">
            <param name='loop' value="false">
            <EMBED type='application/x-mplayer2'
                    pluginspage='http://microsoft.com/windows/mediaplayer/en/download/'
                    id='mediaPlayer' name='mediaPlayer' displaysize='6' autosize='1' 
                    bgcolor='darkblue' showcontrols="true" showtracker='1' 
                    showdisplay='1' showstatusbar='1' videoborder3d='1' width="420" height="380"
                    src="rtp://224.168.116.253:4568" autostart="true" designtimesp='5311' loop="true">
            </EMBED>
        </OBJECT>
        <br />
    </body>
</html>
```